# Connection between A-star search and integer programming, extending A-star

Tags: search, optimization, routes, path-finding, a-star

Does anyone have a good reference for the connections between A-star search and more general integer programming formulations for a Euclidean shortest path problem?

In particular I'm interested in how one modifies A-star to cope with additional (perhaps path-dependent) constraints, if it makes sense to use a general-purpose LP/IP solver to tackle constrained shortest path problems like this or if something more specialised is required to achieve the same kind of performance obtained by A-star together with a good heuristic.

Not afraid of maths, but most of the references I'm finding for more complex shortest path problems aren't very explicit about how they relate to heuristic-guided algorithms like A* (perhaps because 'A*' is hard to google for...)

Comment: *"how one modifies A-star to cope with additional (perhaps path-dependent) constraints"* - what do you mean by "path-dependent constraints?"  As in, if this edge is taken then this other edge isn't allowed?  My intuition tells me that the general case of this problem will be NP-Complete.

Comment: I'm talking about constraints like: if this path segment is activeIt is almost certainly NP-complete yes.

Comment: Oops hit return too soon. Yeah, exactly that sort of thing, and some generalisations like "if this sequence of edges is active then that sequence of edges is mandatory". Wouldn't be surprised if it were NP-complete in general (reducible to SAT perhaps). It can be expressed and solved as a linear integer program with boolean variables, but I'm looking for some insight into how one might develop or adapt more domain-specific heuristic-guided path-finding algorithms like A* for this sort of task, given that in practice the constraints are expected to be quite simple/local and not pathological.

Comment: Then you'll have to define more precisely what *"simple/local"* means, and then we can see if that more-constrained problem is also NP-Complete.  As it stands *(assuming it really is NP-Complete)*, integer programming/global-optimization techniques are probably your best bet.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't really expecting to work out the precise details of specialised algorithm on here though, more for pointers to relevant work in the area, in particular for connections between heuristic-guided path-finding and more general combinatorial search algorithms.

Comment: If I was to make "local" precise though, I could place an upper bound on the shortest path distance between any pair of edges involved in a single constraint. Although in practise the problem domain doesn't come with hard guarantees, so it might only be only a soft/probabilistic bound (95% of constraints within a radius of 2 edges, maybe a handful further than that with no hard upper limit). Obviously I realise that without a hard guarantee it'll be exponential time in the worst case, and am OK with that, the worst case will almost never occur and if it does I can time out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into constraint optimization, specifically soft-arc consistency, and constraint satisfaction, specifically arc-consistency, or other types of consistency such as i-consistency. Here's some references about constraint optimization:

[1] Thomas Schiex. Soft constraint Processing. http://www.inra.fr/mia/T/schiex/Export/Ecole.pdf

[2] Dechter, Rina. Constraint Processing, 1st ed. Morgan Kaufmann, San Francisco, CA 94104-3205, 2003.

[3] Kask, K., and Dechter, R. Mini-Bucket Heuristics for Improved Search. In Proc. UAI-1999 (San Francisco, CA, 1999), Morgan Kaufmann, pp. 314–323.

[3] might be especially interesting because it deals with combining A* with a heuristic of the type you seem to be interested in.

I'm not sure whether this helps you. Here's how I got the idea that it might:

Constraint optimization is a generalization of SAT towards optimization and variables with more than two values. A set of soft-constraints, i.e. partial cost functions, and a set of discrete variables define your problem. Typically a branch-and-bound algorithm is used to traverse the search tree that this problem implies. Soft-arc consistency refers to a set of heuristics that use local soft-constraints to compute the approximate distance to the goal node in that search tree, from your current position. These heuristics are used within the branch-and-bound search, much like heuristics are used within A* search.

Branch-and-bound relates to A* over trees much the same way that depth-first search relates to breadth-first search. So, apart from the fact that a DFS-like algorithm (branch-and-bound) is used in this case, and that it is a tree instead of a graph, it looks like (soft)-arc consistency or other types of consistency is what you are looking for.

Unfortunately, while you can in principle use A* in place of branch-and-bound, it is not clear yet (as far as I know) how in general you could combine A* with soft-arc consistency. Going from a tree to a graph might further complicate things, but I don't know that.

So, no final answer, just some stuff to look at as a starter, maybe :).